# GetOrgChart jquery plugin: Word Wrap text field won't work, produces ellipses instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, orgchart

I'm working on an org chart and have noticed that the titles for our patrons are being truncated with an ellipsis.

Is there a way to change the CSS or the file to have a line break?

I'm using the 'Eve' theme. If you're not familiar with GetOrgChart, here is the relevant code:

```
            $("#people").getOrgChart({
            theme: "eve",
            primaryColumns: ["Name", "Title"],
            imageColumn: "Image",
            linkType: "M",
            editable: false,
            dataSource: s
        });
```

.

```
eve: {
    size: [500, 220],
    toolbarHeight: 46,
    textPoints: [{
        x: 5,           //Name Text
        y: 200,
        width: 490
    }, {
        x: 150,         //Title Text
        y: 40,
        width: 350
    }, {
        x: 210,
        y: 65,
        width: 290
    }, {
        x: 210,
        y: 90,
        width: 290
    }, {
        x: 210,
        y: 115,
        width: 290
    }, {
        x: 210,
        y: 140,
        width: 290
    }],
    textPointsNoImage: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 200,
        width: 490
    }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 40,
        width: 490
    }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 65,
        width: 490
    }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 90,
        width: 490
    }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 115,
        width: 490
    }, {
        x: 10,
        y: 140,
        width: 490
    }],
    box: '<path class="get-box" d="M0 0 L500 0 L500 220 L0 220 Z"/>',
    text: '<text width="[width]" class="get-text get-text-[index]" x="[x]" y="[y]"}">[text]</text>',
    image: '<image xlink:href="[href]" x="10" y="-20" height="170" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" width="130"/>'
```

I've also narrowed down the CSS to be this property for the Title text:

```
.get-org-chart .get-oc-c .get-text {
    fill:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

I've tried `width` with `word-wrap: break-word` but it didn't help.
Any advice would be great, thank you.

Comment: Well is the full text actually there or is the chart doing the clipping before outputting?

Comment: That I am unsure of. The JS is very long, and the variable names are not named something helpful, so trying to figure that out is proving to be a challenge..

Comment: Inspecting the element in the DOM with the console would tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the plug-in: GetOrgChart

Looking at the JavaScript: the code checks the width of the computed text length, compares it to the theme's width value (490) -- and if it's greater, will then replace text with ellipses. Unfortunately, Word-wrapping is not an option here, unless you modify the code. Setting the width in the theme may help, but that may cause other problems, such as overlapping into other boxes.

Here is the javascript:

```
getOrgChart._zk = function (a) {
    for (i = 0; i < a._zu.length; i++) {
        var d = a._zu[i].getAttribute("x");
        var c = a._zu[i].getAttribute("width");
        var b = a._zu[i].getComputedTextLength();
        while (b > c) {
            a._zu[i].textContent = a._zu[i].textContent.substring(0, a._zu[i].textContent.length - 4);
            a._zu[i].textContent += "...";
            b = a._zu[i].getComputedTextLength()
        }
    }
};
```